# displaying graph after importing txt file matplotlib

Tags: python, import, matplotlib

I am writing a simple program to output a basic graph after importing a text file. i get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chris1\Desktop\attempt2\ex1.py", line 13, in <module>
    x.append(int(xAndY[0]))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '270.286'
```

my python code looks like this:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = []
y = []

readFile = open ('temp.txt', 'r')

sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    x.append(int(xAndY[0]))
    y.append(int(xAndY[1]))

print x
print y



plt.plot(x, y)

plt.title('example 1')
plt.xlabel('D')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.show()
```

a snippet of my text file looks like this:

```
270.286,4.353,16968.982,1903.115
38.934,68.608,16909.727,1930.394    
190.989,1.148,16785.367,1969.925
```

the issue seems minor but cannot seem to resolve it myself
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A solution

If you want to convert the float values to integers, simply change

```
x.append(int(xAndY[0]))
y.append(int(xAndY[1]))
```

to

```
x.append(int(float(xAndY[0])))
y.append(int(float(xAndY[1])))
```

[image]

### The reason you get an error

You get the error because the built-in function `int` does not accept a string representation of a float as its argument. From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int):

> **int**(*x=0*)
>   **int**(*x, base=10*)
>   ...
>   If *x* is not a number or if base is given, then *x* must be a string or Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix base. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35.

In your case (*x* is not a number, but a string representation of a float), this means the function does not know how to convert the value. This is because with `base=10`, the argument can only contain the digits [0-9], i.e. not `.` (dot), which implies that the string can not be a representation of a float.

---

### A better solution

I'd recommend that you look into [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy-loadtxt), as this is way easier to use:

```
x, y = np.loadtxt('temp.txt',     # Load values from the file 'temp.txt'
                  dtype=int,      # Convert values to integers
                  delimiter=',',  # Comma separated values
                  unpack=True,    # Unpack to several variables
                  usecols=(0,1))  # Use only columns 0 and 1
```

which produces the same `x` and `y` lists as in your code after correction.

With this modification your code can be cut down to

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x, y = np.loadtxt('temp.txt', dtype=int, delimiter=',',
                  unpack=True, usecols=(0,1))

plt.plot(x, y)

plt.title('example 1')
plt.xlabel('D')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple, just replace the `int` conversion with `float`:

```
for plotPair in sepFile:
    xAndY = plotPair.split(',')
    x.append(float(xAndY[0]))
    y.append(float(xAndY[1]))
```

That will fix the error.

Comment: It will indeed fix the error, but it will also give different data.

Comment: I continue to get an error 'could not convert string to float.'